# Get all data from activeselection with activecell

Tags: c#, ms-project

I'm trying to do a small addin on c# and I'd like to get all the data from my activeselection
So I tried with the command **Application.ActiveCell;**, but I'm only able to get the value of my first cell
I tried many things but nothing is working
Someone has an idea of what I could do?

Comment: Can your addin access **Application.Selection**??

Comment: Yes of course
I can get the value of the first cell but I don't know how to acces to all cells from my selection

Comment: Is the Application object Excel or MS Project?

Comment: it is a msproject object
As the getfield don't work with all of my customfield, I'd like to use this way

Comment: The [ActiveSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/selection-object-project) object has a collection of tasks (or resources) and fields. Loop through the tasks and fields to get the values. If you get stuck, **post your code**. BTW: `GetField` does work with custom fields, use [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-fieldnametofieldconstant-method-project) to get the Field ID to supply to the [GetField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/task-getfield-method-project) method.

Comment: No I can't understand why but in some view the same field returns values with the FielNameToFieldConstant but in other view (in the same project)
the same view returns the error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException or the field taskname returns all the time this error